# why receiving rate is not zero when not browsing?

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet

When I have no browser opened and no updates, or any other files under downloading, *System Monitor* still shows non-zero *Receiving* rate as shown below. Why?
[image]

Comment: It can be interesting to find out where all these connections are coming from. Install `tcpdump` and run it for a while; figure out what standard port numbers are used for. Most outgoing traffic will be ARP packets going out to the LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network activity comes from a variety of processes, and not just your web browser. On my machine right now I see activity from an email client, file sync, music streaming, and more. System updates, clock synchronisation, error reporting, and other background processes also use data.

To track which application is sending or receiving network traffic, try the **nethogs** package.

To install:

```
sudo apt install nethogs
```

To use:

```
sudo nethogs
```

To exit nethogs press <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: Should I concern about such rows in output,`?     root     unknown TCP`, where `PID` is `?` ?

Comment: @Alish No, I have the same row when I run it. See [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401197/how-can-i-close-a-root-process-unknown-tcp-that-shows-up-in-nethogs) for more info.